# How to fix some broken tags

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have some broken tags in my input that I like to fix in my xslt.
I have searched and tried different things, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Input:

`<p>Some text <span class="italic">broken </span><span class="italic">tag</span><span class="italic">s</span> in my content which is <span class="italic">really </span><span class="italic">annoying</span>.</p>`

Desired output:

`<p>Some text <span class="italic">broken tags</span> in my content which is <span class="italic">really annoying</span>.</p>`

Can someone help me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work on your example, but may not be generic enough for other cases.

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="string(@class)">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <span class="{current-grouping-key()}"> 
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/node()"/>
                    </span>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>  
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for me. It's like you said, a little more complex, because of nesting of the span-elements in other inline-elements (bold, emphasis, etc..) but I placed the grouping in a seperate template which I call in all those cases. That works for my case now, but I don't know if that's the proper way to do it.